# Form displaying wrong selected value in angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript

Update form is displaying wrong selected value, while there is a value with selected attribute set to true ?

```
 <div class="form-group col-md-6">
  <label for="inputModel">Model</label>
  <select id="inputModel" class="form-control" formControlName="modelId">
    <option selected disabled [hidden]="serviceCar.model">Select model</option>
    <option *ngFor="let model of models" value="{{model.id}}"
      [attr.selected]="serviceCar.model && serviceCar.modelId === model.id">
      {{model.name}}</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

[image: Photo to help understand]

Comment: Are the model ids unique?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to guess from that code snippet, but you're probably mixing concerns. Based on the `formControlName="modelId"` attribute I can guess you have a Reactive Form somewhere. But at the same time you're trying to set value manually as selected. You should either not use Reactive Forms at all, or if you use them, then do something like this in your component instead:

```
this.form.patchValue({
    modelId: selectedModelId
});
```

And then in your template bind it to `(change)` handler:

```
<select id="inputModel" class="form-control" formControlName="modelId"
        (change)="handleSelection($event)">
```

What you have here instead is that the `formControlName` directive reflects some value from your form model somewhere else, overwriting what you're trying to set in the `[attr.selected]`. If you want to set some value to that field you have to manipulate the model of the Reactive Form, not in the template.